# What is the probability that a random selection of 2 choices from 6 options are the correct answer choices?

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a random selection of 2 choices from 6 options are the correct answer choices? (Given that there are only two correct answer choices)

Comment: If you must choose $2$ out of $6$, then how many possibilities are there?

Comment: I also wanted to know how 2/6 * 1/5 (=1/15) is wrong answer.

Comment: Peculiar. There are $\binom{6}{2}=15$ possible pairs of choices and only one of them
is the correct pair of choices. That implies a probability of $\frac{1}{15}$.
Something must be wrong here (maybe your teacher, but I don't think
that's 'probable'). If this is really the question then $\frac{1}{15}$ is the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with trying all choices (15)

1 & 2 , 1 & 3 , 1 & 4 , 1 & 5 , 1 & 6

2 & 3 , 2 & 4 , 2 & 5 , 2 & 6

3 & 4 , 3 & 5 , 3 & 6

4 & 5 , 4 & 6

5 & 6

and then check how many are correct if for example 3 and  5 are the correct answers.